# Mercurial: Refer to values set in hgrc

Tags: mercurial

Mercurial's `log` command contains a parameter `-u USER` to filter the changesets such that only the changes by `USER` are displayed. I was wondering if there is a way to tell `hg` to take the username from my `.hgrc`.

I am aware that I can simply use an alias like the following in `.hgrc`:

```
[alias]
ulog = log -u MYUSERNAME
```

Unfortunately, if I want to share parts of my configuration with other people by using `%include`, thus they will not be able to use the alias in the intended way.

So, my question is: Is there a way to refer to other variables in a `.hgrc` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer to other values in the `.hgrc` when defining a new value. However, for this particular case you're in luck: things like `~foo` and `$USER` are expanded in aliases. This means that you can define your alias like this

```
[alias]
ulog = log -u $USER
```

This is not quite what you ask for, but if all your users are on Linux, it should work fine.